# Distance function under diffeomorphism of manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, general-relativity

community,

I am concerned with measuring distances of systems under diffeomorphisms. 
Concrety, I consider a smooth diffeomorphism $\varphi: M\rightarrow N$ from the smooth differentiable manifold $M$ to $N$. The distance function $d$ is given in either $M$ or $N$, say $N$ for our purposes. I would like to infer a suitable distance function for the manifold $M$. My professor suggested the technique pull-back. However, that was not what I was looking for since, this would give me the distance the points have in $N$ with the points of $M$. I am looking for something that is able to express how the distribution of distances of all points in the manifold changed, whether cluster occur ect. However, how can I infer a distance function for that purpose?

I may just be looking for the right term or concept. Please, note that the dimensionalities of my manifolds usually exceed 10.

PS I am having a physics background but never got into relativity theory whatsoever.

Thank you so much for suggestions.

Cheers

Comment: Do you mean that $d$ is a given distance function on $N$ in the sense of metric spaces? If so, you can just define $d_M(x,y) = d(\varphi(x),\varphi(y))$ and this will be a distance function on $M$.

Comment: Hey Lee, well it may also concern the KL-divergence.

Comment: Also I am wondering: Isn't that just pull-back?

Comment: I've never heard of KL-divergence, but a quick look at Wikipedia makes it clear that it would only make sense if $M$ and $N$ are endowed with more structure, such as probability measures or Riemannian metrics. And yes, the formula I wrote down for $d_M$ is the pullback of $d$ to $M$.

Comment: But than in both manifolds two arbitrary points would always have the same distance $d_M(x,y)=d_M(\varphi(x),\varphi(y))=d(u,v),x,y\in M ,u,v\in N$,right? I would like to make a statement about how the wrapping of the space (diffeomorphism) influenced the distances of points in both spaces, e.g., did the mapping bring certain points closer together and others further away?

Comment: Am I asking the wrong questions?

Comment: Yes, I guess you are. You have to figure out what kind of metric or probability structure each manifold is endowed with at the start, and then ask a specific question about how $\phi$ relates to those two structures.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time Mr. Lee. So you are saying I must make some assumption about the underlying metric of each space separately and that the diffeomorphism can not help me to find a suitable metric. Does it make sense to apply the same metric to both manifolds. If not, what requirements would the distance function on $M$ have to fulfill in order to be able to compare the distribution of distances of points in $N$ and $M$. Could you maybe also recommend what to read about to get an understanding of what I am looking for?

Comment: "The same metric" doesn't make sense unless $M=N$.  I'm no expert, but you might look into optimal transport theory to see if it addresses the kind of issues you're interested in.